# jQuery UI Datepicker - Custom button - Custom text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, datepicker

I need to add a custom button in jQuery UI Datepicker, and when the user clicks that button, set a value to input (a string of text) and close the popup. Is possible this?

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/7Wygg/

```
showButtonPanel: true,
beforeShow: function (input) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var buttonPane = $(input)
            .datepicker("widget")
            .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");

        var btn = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">Custom</button>');
        btn.unbind("click")
        .bind("click", function () {
            //$.datepicker._clearDate(input);
            alert('custom text');
        });

        btn.appendTo(buttonPane);

    }, 1);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Modified answer due to comment**

You mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7Wygg/10/ ?

I just added

```
$(input).datepicker("hide");
$(input).val("custom text");
```

Comment: Yes, It's perfect.
But I have a lot of datepickers in them same page.
So I can't use $(".datepicker").
Is possible change $(".datepicker") and set $(this)?

Comment: @FeKuLa I modified my answer and the fiddle. This should work for you now.

Comment: interestingly the button disapperas after changing the moth

Comment: True. Then you should add the button in every update event again, like onChangeMonthYear etc

Answer (score 2):

set a demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/7Wygg/8/) and here in **datepicker we can set date like pattern not any other**

```
$(function() {
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    beforeShow: function (input) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var buttonPane = $(input)
                .datepicker("widget")
                .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");

            var btn = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">Custom</button>');
            btn.unbind("click")
            .bind("click", function () {
                //$.datepicker._clearDate(input);
                alert('custom text');
                $(".datepicker").datepicker( "hide" );
                $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", "19/12/2003" );// here in cutom we can set date like pattern not any other

            });

            btn.appendTo(buttonPane);

        }, 1);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: in date picker you cant set text but in any other text-box you can set it is the nature of date-picker dear

Comment: $(".datepicker").val("custom text"); Works! but I need use $this because I have a lot of datepickers

Comment: What about having a custom button with date and time picker both?

Comment: then you need to extend plugin @V.B